# How to serialise Pandas to MessagePack format as a python buffer / memoryview?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, msgpack, memoryview

Pandas has a [DataFrame.to_msgpack()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-msgpack) method for serialising a dataframe to the [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org) format.

It requires a file path or a 'buffer-like' object. If not provided, then it returns the data in a string representation.

My question is how to properly save this data as a buffer-like object without saving it as a string first?

```
#1
string_data = df.to_msgpack()  # returns data as string

#2
memory_buffer = memory view(df.to_msgpack())  # creates a memory view from string

#3
df.to_msgpack('filename.msg')  # return data as binary file

#4
memory_buffer = memoryview(b'')
df.to_msgpack(memory_buffer, append=True)  # would this work?
```

In scenario 4, `df.to_msgpack()` requires a buffer-like object, whereas `memoryview()` requires an input parameter. So one would have to create an 'empty' memory view and then pass this to the `to_msgpack()` method. Then append the data. Though I wonder if this will lead to artefacts when unpacking the data.

With scenario 2, is it correct to think that a memory view of a string would be equivalent to a byte-array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After perusing the pandas source code it appears that the way to do this is to use python's io.BytesIO() for the buffer:

```
buffer = io.BytesIO()
df.to_msgpack(buffer, append=False, compress='zlib')
```

This appears to work nicely. Note that the compress option appears a bit spotty in release 0.16.0 but seems to be resolved in the master.